Installing LyX 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy)
The latest version of LyX, 2.4.0, was released on May 31, 2024. I attempted to install this version on my system running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy) by following the steps provided in the official LyX wiki at LyXOnUbuntu. However, despite my efforts, I could only install the older version, LyX 2.3.6.1-1, on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy).
I am unsure if there is a specific step or prerequisite that I might be missing which is preventing me from successfully installing the latest version of LyX. Could anyone provide guidance or clarify the correct procedure for installing LyX 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy)?
Here’s what I did:

Followed the instructions from the LyX wiki page.
Added the appropriate repositories as mentioned.
Updated the package lists and attempted the installation.

Despite these steps, the installation defaults to the older version. I would appreciate any insights or additional steps needed to install LyX 2.4.0.

The latest version in that PPA was published in 2021: https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release. I suggest you undo what you did and revert to Ubuntu's official repo. If you really need the latest, you will either need to find an alternative PPA - and make sure you trust it - or you will need to build it yourself. (Instructions for building at the link you provided.) More generally, you are using the wrong Linux distro if you often want the latest versions of software. If it is just one or two things you need to build, OK, but, if not, a different distro might work better.

You may need to compile the source. This sounds intimidating but shouldn't be too difficult. You could try the following:

Run sudo apt-get build-dep lyx. This will install all the dependencies needed to build LyX. Note that the dependencies will be for building 2.3.x since that's what version is in the Ubuntu repositories. But hopefully they're similar to what you need to build 2.4.0.

Clone the LyX source with the following command git clone "git://git.lyx.org/lyx".

Inside that cloned directory, switch to the version you want. You say 2.4.0, but I would suggest 2.4.x: git checkout 2.4.x.

Then, inside that directory you need to build LyX. One option is to use my script lyxbuild available here: https://gitlab.com/scottkosty/lyx-tester/. I'm the only one who has been using it though so I don't know if it will work for you. If you get an error, let me know.



Thank you, @scottkosty, for your helpful answer. I will give it a try soon and will update you on how it goes.

@MYaseen208 did you find a solution?

@Delosari: Not yet.
